# How to enable word spellcheck with openxml sdk in vb dotnet

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to generate a word document by substituting certain placeholder words by other texts.
The sources of these texts can vary, either it's plain text or RTF (inserted with [altchunks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk?view=openxml-2.8.1)).

**The problem**

This substitution doesn't seem to trigger the spellchecker in word, which is a requirement (users need to be alerted when they've made a typo in the substituted text).
A few errors (around 3) do get highlighted, but there's no pattern.

I suspect substituting text doesn't set make the content "dirty", so the spellcheck isn't triggered.

**What I've tried**

I've tried implementing a few supposed solutions I found online
which I unfortunately can't find anymore. one of them was:

```
var hideSpellingErrors = new HideSpellingErrors();            
hideSpellingErrors.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(False);
document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(hideSpellingErrors);
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

I've been googling for about a day now and I'm completely stumped by how little documentation this problem has.

Comment: Without seeing the full document it's hard to say what is the exact reason. But one thing that comes to mind is RunProperties NoProof. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.noproof?view=openxml-2.8.1
If it is set to true in default document, spell check will not happen.